# How to solve this equation for $r$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem....
I have to express unknown "r" from from this equation:

$$Y\times r=(-Z\times 2r\times L)+(z\times K^2\times 0.5L)$$

Can someone help me ?

Comment: This matematic is too hard

Comment: show some effort from your side

Comment: do you want find out value of r in terms of Y,Z,L,K?

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  move the term containing $r$ to the left by adding $2ZLr$ to both sides, then use the distributive law to write the left as (something)$r$, then divide both sides by (something)